# What is the meaning of the parameter added to links in the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™?

Tags: support, stack-exchange-button

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does this URL have “?as=1” at the end of it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120887/why-does-this-url-have-as-1-at-the-end-of-it)

When following a link to a site which is shown on the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™, in the "all sites" tab, I noticed the link has a "as=1" appended. For example, clicking on *Wordpress*, I am taken to https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/?as=1.

What is the meaning of that parameter? Does it change the shown questions?

Comment: It's for analytics purposes.