# What does the different appending characters at the end of a link do?

Tags: support, sharing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does this URL have “?as=1” at the end of it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120887/why-does-this-url-have-as-1-at-the-end-of-it)

I note that some question links have funny characters appended to the end of the links. Some of the notable appending characters include rq=1, atw=1, stw=1 and cb=1.

What is the use of these characters and how do they work?

Comment: My guess: Tracking purposes...