# The "?cb=1" added to questions accessed via CB prevents one-boxing in chat

Tags: feature-request, support, chat, onebox, community-bulletin

I noticed something on the SE sites and I don't know if others did (no MSO questions on it, though) so I'm taking it to the public.

If you access a Meta question, the address bar will show a structure such as `site.stackexchange.com/questions/(ID number)/title-of-the-question`. But if you access the same question by using the Community Bulletin, it adds `?cb=1` at the end of that address. I thought the number 1 referred to the position in the CB, but no, it's the same in the other cases.

Also: If you paste the address in chat, the system will usually one-box the question. But this *does not* happen whenever the address being pasted is the one carrying `?cb=1`.

Is it intentional behavior? If not, perhaps it should be fixed. In any case, I'd like to ask to fix the one-boxing problem so I'll be tagging this [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).

Comment: *"I thought the number 1 referred to the position in the CB, but no, it's the same in the other cases."* Looks like a flag (`cb=true`)

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ Ah ok :) I understand the correlation true=1, false=0, but what are you referring to/do you mean by "flag"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7630449/396458

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ Ah! I got it! The system is basically saying "Yes, this was accessed via Community Bulletin", right?

Comment: @Alenanno yep - this happens in [a number of instances](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142535/176080), all of which are ?flag=1

Comment: The one-boxing of Meta posts under "Featured"/"Featured on Meta" now seems to work fine even with `?cb=1` appended to the question URL, but the one-boxing of posts under "The Overflow Blog" and "Upcoming Events" does not work unless `?cb=1` is removed.