# Hash at the end of question URLs

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign

I have noticed that Stack Overflow questions are now displaying a Hash / Number sign in the address bar, at the end of the URL. Example

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14931337/clear-the-screen-and-buffer#
```

Replication steps

- go to [`stackoverflow.com`](http://stackoverflow.com)
- click a question

example

[image: hash]

Comment: This happens only when you click on comments.

Comment: not happening for me..

Comment: not happening here either

Comment: I repro this on Stack Overflow, but not on Meta. I ran into it earlier today, too, when I was editing or something. It blocked my back button from working properly. I just assumed I fat-fingered something, but maybe there's more to it.

Comment: No repro on SO.

Comment: Either it fixed itself by now, or only Firefox issue...

Comment: Just reprod this on new Chrome: Version 22.0.1229.79. If you're quick you notice an `#mlsy` tacked on the end before it quickly changes to just `#` (i.e. `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15075893/upload-files-by-ajax-beginform-in-asp-net-mvc3#mlsy`). The hash isn't initially part of the links URLs (from the questions page) but only seems to happen when linked (that is, you can hit the same URL directly and it won't happen).

Comment: Appears to happen on the last line of the `full-c.js` file (_nth_ call to `$(window).one("scroll",
function(){k.resolve()})}}}}();StackExchange.ready(function(){});`, if that's not a red herring).

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment You un-disappointed me. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're just noticing a small bit of analytic tracking there.

Sometimes when we make changes we want to measure what sort of difference it made, and this `#mlsy` thing-y (like [`?as=1` before it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120887/why-does-this-url-have-as-1-at-the-end-of-it)) is one of them.  It'll go away in a week or so if I remember the numbers correctly.

Comment: "what sort of difference it made" - it's making me have to click back *twice* to get back to the question list after clicking a question, and this in turn is making me a sad pony.

Comment: @AakashM hmm, that shouldn't be happening... I'll see if I can repro and get a fix in the next deploy.

Comment: @KevinMontrose was seeing it then but not now, where "it" is SO only, not other SE sites, and involves frontpage links having `#mlsy` on them, which script altered to `#` on the question page (but leaving a spurious entry in history)

Comment: @AakashM yeah, I've found and fixed it on our dev tier.  It'll go out with the next build, which should be shortly.