# Now have to hit back twice to get back to questions?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I think it started about 2-3 days ago -- On SO I noticed when I click on a question, and then click "Back" (I use the mouse button, but that's not really relevant), I have to click it twice to get back to the question list.

If you click on question, notice how a "#" is appended to the end of the URL. If you click back once, it goes away. Then you have to click back again to get back to the questions.

Is it just me, or is this new? What is the point? It makes navigation a little frustrating.

It has been noted in [Hash at the end of question URLs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174687/hash-at-the-end-of-question-urls) but I'm specifically bringing it up because of the impact on navigation.  But if that answer is correct and it'll go away in a week or so, I suppose its a non-issue.

Comment: Funny, but I've been here for nearly three years, and I don't remember ever having to use the back button.  I trained myself ages ago never to use it, because there are too many websites that just don't handle the back button properly.

Comment: I use it to quickly get back to the list of questions I was looking at. It's convenient with the way loading up questions works.

Comment: Same topic, yes, but it doesn't address the nav issue, which is my concern. Not the existence of the hash... (but not in my search I didn't see that so thx).

Comment: The hash is causing this so the answer there is pretty much the answer here as well.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Yes, it answers why it is there, but I hope it is noted the impact it has on general nav... which was the reason for my post. If it is something they are testing for analytics or for whatever reason, I think this should be taken into consideration.

Comment: More information needed! what browser and OS are you using? Not happening here running Ubuntu 12.04 in FF or Chromium

Comment: Windows 7 FF 19.0.2 and also on FF at work which is likely some older version. Not happening in Safari on phone or Chrome on Win7. FF just updated to 20.0 and it isn't an issue.

Comment: I'm assuming you're running some form of Windows then... ???

Comment: It's not how stack works. It's your browser. Any click on an anchor counts as a navigation

Comment: I can't seem to duplicate this on any of my machines using multiple browsers.

Comment: @ColeJohnson I don't think my browser starting acting different in the past 2 days. It coincided with a change to the site.

Comment: @ElefantPhace just VPNd into work which has FF 3.6.14 and it no longer is an issue. I think they have removed this from happening.

Comment: interesting! Is it still doing it right now on your machine?

Comment: @ElefantPhace no... its a conspiracy to make me look stupid :) Like I said, its not doing it on my work PC FF either, and it hasn't updated like my home PC  FF did before it started working.

Comment: @ColeJohnson what I mean is, one click = two back buttons.

Comment: I think this is something that "happens" randomly for random users, kind of like the [SSSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secondary_Security_Screening_Selection) in USA flights. @Cole you are correct but the issue here is that there are indeed two redirections, one after the other. First to the  question page then another redirection to the same page but ending with "#".