# # sign appended to SO question links in Chrome

Tags: support, google-chrome, osx, mac, windows-7

I'm on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) and when I click on a question to view the page pulls up but with a `#` at the end of the link in the address bar.

So I am scrolled to the "**Post Your Answer**" textfield instead of the being at the top of the page.

Not a big deal, but it is bothersome. It's not doing this on any other site (i.e. [graphicdesign.stackexchange.com](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com) or [wordpress.stackexchange.com](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com)).

I've also cleared the tab and opened the site in a new tab, but it's persistent.

**UPDATE**

Tried the following:

1. Removed the tab and reopened in another tab - same result
2. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> to clear cache - same result
3. Closed the browser and re-opened - same result
4. Only happening when going to the [Top Questions](http://stackoverflow.com).
5. Clicking on [Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) or [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered) works fine.
6. **Confirmed it's only in Chrome. Firefox and IE are not doing this for me.**

**UPDATE 2**

Seems I'm not crazy, because this is happening with my Mac now as well. I have Chrome (Version 27.0.1453.93) on my Mac and it's the same result.

So it's Chrome Version 27.0.1453.94 on Windows 7 and Version 27.0.1453.93 on Mac OSX 10.7.5

Comment: I'm using chrome and this does not happen to me.  Can you ctrl f5 to clear cache.

Comment: What version of Chrome?  I am not reproducing this on Chrome for Mac

Comment: Could you copy/paste a url from your address bar?

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this. Chrome 27 on Linux. Do you have any extensions or userscripts that might cause this?

Comment: @bluefeet Version 27.0.1453.94 m

Comment: @AndrewBarber here is the first question on the list: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16860987/session-value-gets-deleted-if-an-equally-named-variable-gets-nulled

Comment: @hammar only extension I have is the Stackexchange, but I'ts not setup.

Comment: [Hash at the end of question URLs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174687/hash-at-the-end-of-question-urls) - Although, there's no mention of users being bumped down to the Post Your Answer box there. That shouldn't happen.

Comment: @JonH I tried `ctrl+F5` but still happening.

Comment: @animuson Sorry, should have searched for `hash` instead of the actual symbol `#`. Although the hash is at the end, no keyword as the user mentioned for analytics. I'm gonna close the browser and try again.

Comment: @ckpepper02: From what I can tell, the hash gets changed to just `#` as the page is loading.

Comment: @animuson Ok, it's only happening on the Top questions page. If I go to [Questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions), it doesn't happen.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Tried it this morning and it's working fine again. No hash, and no page jump.

I guess the Techs fixed whatever it was.

Comment: I'm still seeing the issue (Chrome 27.0.1453.93, Ubuntu 13.04).