# Why do Stack Exchange sites add a hyperlink inside H1 tag, pointing to the same page?

Tags: discussion, design, hyperlinks

Why do Stack Exchange sites add a hyperlink inside the H1 tag, linking to the same page?

For example, [on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/760926/error-in-eclipse-on-run-android-project):

```
<h1 itemprop="name">
    <a class="question-hyperlink"
        href="/questions/760926/error-in-eclipse-on-run-android-project"></a>
</h1>
```

What's the benefit of hyperlinks to the same page?

Comment: I guess it would be so you can easily deeplink from another page. Technical about Stack Exchange sites should be posted on Meta Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

Links to SE questions often include unnecessary clutter in the URL. For instance, if someone linked to a specific answer inside a question, or had some tracking/referral code in the URL. Adding a link to the canonical URL for the question as part of the question header is a convenient way to either refresh the current page without the ancillary URL stuff, or copy the canonical URL directly.

This is very common practice in all content sits I know. Most, if not all WordPress themes do it to blog post headers, and I'm sure other CMSs do too.

Comment: True, but note that referrals are already taken out when short URLs are rewritten when following such links. Any other tracking you might see are the [usage URL parameters](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120887/why-does-this-url-have-as-1-at-the-end-of-it) such as `?rq=1`.

Comment: @Arjan: Aye, but in situations where you followed a link to a particular *answer* using the H1 A is a convenient way to get a link to the question.

Comment: Yes, @Matt, no doubt about that; I was just referring to the referral codes mentioned in the answer. (I wish there was an easy way to [get full URLs for answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114088/provide-an-easily-discoverable-way-to-get-the-full-url-to-an-answer) too!)