# click on user picture links to the same page

Tags: discussion, feature-request, profile-page, profile-picture

Just today I noticed that it is possible to click on the user picture (e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet).

> [image]

I had the feeling that there is some more functionality behind but it seems it just simply links to the profile page and in the case of StackOverflow it links to the very same page. So it results in a refresh of that page. On other communities it links to the activity tab of the user.

I personally was confused and I would suggest to remove the link if I am not mistaken by the meaning of this link.

Similar but not the same issue: [Why do Stack Exchange sites add a hyperlink inside H1 tag, pointing to the same page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232432/)

Comment: To answer your question below, on Metas, particularly on Feature Requests, downvotes are simply a person saying "I disagree with this post". It doesn't have the same meaning of a question being poorly researched or anything like that. :) Here's a [guide to votes on Meta](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: Added a screenshot with FHRC, just out of habit.

Answer (score 5):

It's kind of "permalink" inside the page itself, like question title.

It's useful for those who know about it, e.g. when inside some filters in the profile page ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=activity&sort=comments)) I know I can click the profile picture to get back to the "default" view of the profile page.

Please don't remove it.

Comment: useful for what?

Comment: Added an example

Comment: got it. Just one more remark: According to the permalink under the question title I would find it less confusing to link the user name instead of the picture. But that's a minor issue.

Comment: Is there any explanation in the help pages about the idea of permalink behind picture / question title which I have overseen? If yes please downvote me to indicate that it's low research effort. Or does the downvote mean: "don't change  anything"

Comment: Yes my downvote means that I don't agree with your request to remove the link. As for help pages, nothing about it - it's just one among many "hidden features" of Stack Exchange.